# How to convert particular string to date in Talend

Tags: talend, date-conversion

In talend

Oct 21 - Oct 27 (2019)

is there any way to convert above text to date format, I only want 21 oct 2019 as 21/10/2019 format

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is not simple, as you have two dates on one field only, with Year appearing only once.

You can achieve this with tMap_1 --> tNormalize --> tMap_2

In tMap_1 you will have to separate "MMM-dd" from "YYYY", which appears at the end of your string. Use split method on your input field :

```
myFlow.myDateField.split("\\(")[0] will give you the part with `Oct 21 - Oct 27`
myFlow.myDateField.split("\\(")[1] will give you the part with the year.
```

Use `StringHandling.LEFT` to get the year only, without the closing parenthesis.
Use StringHandling.TRIM to get rid of extra spaces.
Then you will have two fields in the output.

You can then use tNormalize (normalize on "-") to put the year in front of every MMM/dd field.
In the output you'll have two rows and two columns :

```
"Oct 21|2019"
"Oct 27|2019"
```

In the final tMap , concatenate your two input fields as you wish, and use `TalendDate.parseDateLocale` to parse your date. (TalendDate.parseDate won't work as you have "Oct", which requires parseDateLocale method to work).